# how to mount multiple snapshots using vdfuse

Tags: 12.04, mount, virtualbox

As per `vdfuse` command help:

```
DESCRIPTION: This Fuse module uses the VirtualBox access library to open a 
VirtualBox supported VD image file and mount it as a Fuse file system.  The
mount point contains a flat directory containing the files EntireDisk,
Partition1 .. PartitionN.  These can then be loop mounted to access the
underlying file systems
Version: 0.83

USAGE: vdfuse [options] -f image-file mountpoint
    -h  help
    -r  readonly
    -t  specify type (VDI, VMDK, VHD, or raw; default: auto)
    -f  VDimage file
    -s  Snapshot file(s) to load on top of the image file
    -a  allow all users to read disk
    -w  allow all users to read and write to disk
    -g  run in foreground
    -v  verbose
    -d  debug

-s (Snapshot file(s) to load on top of the image file)
```

In which format it accept multiple snapshots?

Comment: Sorry, I've read the man page for vdfuse under 12.04 and the -s switch you refer to doesn't exist. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You can see this switch in "using it" section of https://github.com/Thorsten-Sick/vdfuse

Comment: Ok.   I'll bite. Where exactly is the "Using It section"? Can you link to it directly? I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: https://github.com/Thorsten-Sick/vdfuse#using-it

Comment: Which format(s) have you tried? can you give us an example command line that failed and the error that you received (or what happened when you tried it)?

Answer (score 2):

I need to do the same thing now and had to look up the source code in https://github.com/Thorsten-Sick/vdfuse/blob/master/vdfuse.c.

According to the code, you simply issue multiple `-s` switches to use more than one snapshot images.